# listbox scrollbar moves without any command

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing an ASP.NET practice website with a listbox in it. When I select an item , the scrollbar suddenly moves. Why is this? Is this common? Or am I doing something wrong?......... Suggestions appreciated I'm posting screenshots of the problem.

[image]

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Refresh" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="120px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="202px"></asp:ListBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Insert" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button3_Click" Text="Update" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" OnClick="Button4_Click" Text="Delete" />

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{   

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void refresh()
    {

        ListBox1.Items.Clear();

        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName,LastName,EmployeeID FROM Employees", cnn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr.GetString(0) + " " + dr.GetString(1),dr.GetInt32(2).ToString()));
            }
        }

        cnn.Close();

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //refresh
    {
        refresh();
    }

    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @numara", cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numara", ListBox1.SelectedValue);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                TextBox1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
                TextBox2.Text = dr.GetString(1);
            }
        }

        cnn.Close();

    }
    protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //insert
    {
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employees (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@CalisanAdi, @CalisanSoyadi)", cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalisanAdi", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalisanSoyadi", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();

        refresh();

    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //update
    {
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Employees SET FirstName = @CalisanAdi , LastName = @CalisanSoyadi WHERE EmployeeID = @numara", cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numara", ListBox1.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalisanAdi", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalisanSoyadi", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();

        refresh();

    }

    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //delete
    {
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @numara", cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numara", ListBox1.SelectedValue);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();

        refresh();

    }
}
```

Comment: please post some code

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat check please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because the page is being posted back when you select an item in the list, this is expected behaviour from ASP.net. The page is being refreshed and the item you previously chose is being selected in the listbox.